# Another phrase for "The land and its people"

Tags: expressions

I am writing a book on tourism and have a section that talks about the land, its cuisine, language, culture, festivals etc. Is there a phrase that can act as a section header?

I am avoiding a cliché like "The land and its people"

Comment: Can you provide more information regarding the intended audience and/or purpose? If this is something scientific/academic in nature, then you may lean more towards something like "Demographics, Geography and Culture". Otherwise, if this is to be something practical (used by actual tourists), then that could definitely change the language - e.g."Cultural and Natural Attractions".

Comment: It is a commissioned book by the Tourism board and is the language is a little elitist. It is for investors who would look at investing in tourism. However it is a coffee table book so the language has to be better than the common tourist book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for giving the context.  Say the country you want to write about is Sri Lanka.  Then your title could be

**The Cultural Richness of Sri Lanka**

My idea is to use the old idea of connecting toothpaste with sex appeal.  You want these investors to imagine themselves getting richer!

Comment: You're close it is actually Tamil Nadu with references to Sri Lanka :).